# c# Infragistics UltraChart LineChart

Tags: c#, infragistics, charts, graphing

Can someone please provide a simple example of adding a line series to an UltraChart from a data table?  The table has time series values (time values on x-axis, measurement (double) values on the y-axis).

So far the only examples I've seen where time series are added to the Chart are for a finite set of hard-coded datapoints. I want to be able to fee the data series from a selection in the table.

Any thoughts ideas and/or advice is greatly appreciated.  Thanks, Ruben.

Answer (score 1):

1. Define a Numeric Series
2. Loop through each Data row in the Datatable
3. Add Datapoints from the Datarow inside the loop
   `NumericSeries.Points.Add(new NumericTimeDataPoint(System.DateTime.Parse(row["Date"]), row["value1"], "Label Name", false));`
4. Add the Series to the Chart

For Multiple Line Series create as many Series as you want with different columns.

```
NumericTimeSeries waterDataSeries = null;
foreach (DataRow currentRow in myDataTable.Rows)
{
waterDataSeries.Points.Add(new NumericTimeDataPoint(Convert.ToDateTime(currentRow["Date"]), Convert.ToDouble(currentRow["qtyMeasure"]), "Water", false));
}
Chart.Series.Add(waterDataSeries);
```